# remove element of struct from vector of struct with erase-remove-idiom

Tags: c++, vector, erase-remove-idiom

I have a vector of structs and I want to remove an element from the vector with specific values.I know how it can be done for for example a vector of int values using erase remove, but now sure how to do it for a vector of structs:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct file_line{
    string pcounter;
    int optype;
};

int main() {
    vector<file_line> v = {file_line{"aa",1}, file_line{"bb", 2}, file_line{"cc", 5}, file_line{"ddd", 12}};

    v.erase(remove(v.begin(),v.end(),file_line{"cc",5} ), v.end());
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error that I receive:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/predefined_ops.h:241:17: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘file_line’ and ‘const file_line’)
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
```

Comment: Sorry corrected the error

Comment: The error message should be pretty obvious: "no match for ‘operator==’". You need to implement some way to compare two `file_line` structures for equality (using `==`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, the compiler doesn't know how to compare two `file_line` objects. You can provide this comparison yourself by writing:

```
bool operator==(file_line const & a,file_line const & b)
{
    return a.pcounter == b.pcounter and a.optype == b.optype;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ae37q3).